# keyboard doesn't type o p l '

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I own an acer aspire e5 575g, the issue I am having is the keyboard would randomly not register that I have pressed any of the  o p l

I doubt that it is a hardware issue as sometimes it would work normally. I have tried to uninstall the keyboard driver and reinstall it but to no avail, I tried booting into safe mode to see if an app was causing this issue but it was the same in safe mode.

I have found a work around that would get it to work normally for a while, which is to hold the o p l keys then hit esc, somehow this allows the keyboard to register the keys being pressed and that is what I did to write this question

Comment: As the O,P and L are placed adjacently on a QWERTY keyboard, I highly suspect this is a hardware issue. Possible causes: the keyboard might have been damaged by a mechanical impact, there might be dust/debris under the keys, the keyboard might be deformed after taking apart the laptop or by a bloated (i.e. dying) battery or the contact layer of the keyboard might simply be wearing out.

Comment: yet when I do the work around everything works normally as if nothing was wrong in the first place, that is why i have ruled it out from being a hardware issue but i might be wrong